# Insert data into table and immediately select ID number of the row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL table called 'Buyers'. I am taking form data and inserting it into the table on a page called insert.php.

Now, along with the column names for the form fields, I have an Auto-increment ID column in the table. What I want is; once I send the form data to the table, I want to then execute some SQL to get the ID number for the row into which I just inserted the data into.

E.g, I have the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Buyers (name, email, job) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[job]');
```

This will create a row in the 'Buyers' table with the data from form fields 'name', 'email' and 'job'.

This row will have an ID number generated by Auto Increment.

How, then, can I then select that exact ID number? Is there some way to select the most recent row in the table, since that is the row which contains the ID number I want?

Comment: what you are using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`?  because both have inbuilt function like `last_inserted_id` to get the latest id just after insertion. Other wise `SELECT id from buyers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: I'll try the ORDER BY DESC method, I'll see if it works...

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly!

Comment: @J.Brooker  whose solution works for you?

Comment: @Anant:I think your solution will be worked for him, am observing you from few days. your answers are very good in manner.thank you champ.

Comment: @VamsiAbbineni thanks. please maintain this curtsy when you are posting answers and comments. I hope you got me what i want to say. thanks

Comment: @Anant:yeah, will understand. thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Mysqli** : [mysqli_insert_id()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp)

```
<?php
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Buyers (name, email, job) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[job]')");
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con); 
?>
```

**PDO** :  [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Buyers (name, email, job) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['job']);
$stmt->execute();
$last_id = $con->lastInsertId();
?>
```

Assuming `$con` as connection.

**Mysql** : [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
<?php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Buyers (name, email, job) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[job]')");
$last_id = mysql_insert_id(); 
?>
```

[**NOTE**: [The **mysql extension** is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Comment: Thanks @Anant `:)` And Thank You For This Too "*@VamsiAbbineni thanks. please maintain this curtsy when you are posting answers and comments. I hope you got me what i want to say. thanks – Anant*"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM messages x
  JOIN 
      ( SELECT from_id, MAX(time_sent) time_sent GROUP BY from_id ) y
    ON y.from_id = x.from_id 
   AND y.time_sent = x.time_sent;
```

The last part of this puzzle is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This will not work if multiple records are being inserted at the same time from different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Use  mysql_insert_id() to retrive ID. More details - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Note that this function is deprecated. The correct solution would be mysqli_insert_id() or PDO::lastInsertId().